# Extremely long exceptions logs in Spring Boot

Tags: spring, logging, spring-boot, exception, spring-data

Anyone considered how to deal with super long exceptions in logs? That becomes a big pain with Spring Boot, because there is a lot of auto-generated stuff and abstraction on top of abstration.

For instance, if I have a model class and expose it though `@RepositoryRestResource` + `CrudRepository` and hit `@NonNull` or Unique constraint in runtime - I'll get a [super long exception](http://pastebin.com/C1M4jz1Y). Thought there should be some way either to intercept them container-wide and implement some nicer custom logging or maybe some ready to use solution. Thanks in advance for any suggestions

**PS**. There is a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220719/can-the-stacktrace-in-spring-boot-be-reduced), but the suggested solution doesn't seem to be relevant to a modern log4j-2 version

Answer (score 0):

One solution I came up with, is to for exceptions coming form Spring Controllers, which could be sufficient for quite a lot of scenarios.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
public class GlobalExceptionHandler
{
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler({RollbackException.class, DataIntegrityViolationException.class})
    public @ResponseBody
    Map<String,Object> allRollbacks
    (
        Exception exception,
        HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response
    )
    {
        HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<>();
        result.put("error", HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.name());

        Throwable exceptionToLog = Throwables.getRootCause(exception);
        String exceptionClassName = exceptionToLog.getClass().getCanonicalName();
        String message = exceptionToLog.getMessage();

        log.info("{}: {}", exceptionClassName, message);

        result.put("exception", exceptionClassName);
        result.put("message", message);

        return result;
    }
}
```

In this case, we will see a short root cause message in the logs coming from the intercepter, and client will receive JSON response like that:

```
{
 "exception": "org.postgresql.util.PSQLException",
 "error": "BAD_REQUEST",
 "message": "ERROR: duplicate key value violates unique constraint \"ukr6y7o33kjy3vispmnl7if5d4s\"\n  Detail: Key (ref1_id, ref2_id, ref3_id)=(8325842b-ee40-48c3-ab6b-5b914e70b583, 9b0f5356-baa8-4ae2-a149-4f7b1f2dbfda, 9281369c-10a6-4649-bcd3-c18d2e5cd287) already exists."
}
```