# Spring Framework IDEA minimize stack trace output

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Just started with Spring and there's something that bothers me.
If I have an error, like

org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'content' of bean class [hive.form.NotificationForm]: Bean property 'content' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?

The error is clear.
It's clear that I have a "content" thing, in NotificationForm that shouldn't be there.

The console gives me this

[image]

and I have an **explosion** in my eyes with **119 lines of debugging code.**

Is there some way I can minimize the  stack trace info if I make an error ?

Thank you

Comment: haha , thats what actually the stack trace stands for.....now depends on the logging framework you are using , there are custom ways to exclude some patterns. In your case you should exclude Spring's and Thymeleaf's traces. A simple example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33220719/can-the-stacktrace-in-spring-boot-be-reduced) with Log4j. But still , are you sure that this is the desired result ?

Answer (score 2):

Well, that's what the stack looks like when you use Spring + Thymeleaf, you can't really change that. However, you can try to not make it print into the console/log files by either:

- Changing how the logging works (like @AntJavaDev mentioned in the comments)
- Changing how the console works

Since you're using IntelliJ IDEA, you can actually fold those lines in the console by opening **Preferences** > **Editor** > **General** > **Console**. In here, you can add new lines to the list that should be folded.

[image: screenshot of IntelliJ preferences]

In your case you could add:

```
at org.thymeleaf.
at org.apache.catalina.core.
at org.springframework.security.web.
```

This might fold too many lines, but you can finetune it or add exclusions to it. I'm usually not interested in how the whole filter chain looks like so for me personally I added all filters to that list.

If you get an exception now, it will hide those lines from the console, but you will still have an unfold button next to that line, allowing you to toggle it.